# How do we send simple message type elements on soap header to external webservice

Tags: wsdl2apex, wsdl

We have to consume a WSDL in salesforce where we need to send a soap header element which is of simple data type to an external webservice. The problem is that wsdl2apex parser rejects the simple data type and when i convert this to a complex type, it ends up as duplicate on the soap request`

```
  <xsd:element name="Service">
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="loan.CreateLead" />
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="MajorVersion">
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="1" />
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="MinorVersion">
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
```

soap:body use="literal" />

You would notice the header message has 3 elements of simple type Service, MajorVersion and MinorVersion and the wsdl binding sends these elements as soap header. I know enumeration and restrictions tags are not allowed on call outs. So the question, what is the simple xsd tag for Service, MajorVersion and MinorVersion i can use which should be simple type format which would allow me to get through the apex2wsdl parser and get the expected results?

Comment: I am uploading the actual wsdl for your reference here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3g0ogHiFUVNS0ZMRWVIS2FnVUU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you upload this wsdl to your org, it would fail on the gwheader element. I want the equivalent simple type for the 3 elements service, majorversion and minor version on document type literal format please? any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but essentially they are all just strings. So you could just drop the restrictions and make them strings. Something like:

```
<xsd:element name="Service" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="MajorVersion" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="MinorVersion" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Just make sure you follow the restrictions when setting the actual values that get passed to the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel for your answer. The bottom line is that if there is header information to be passed from saleforce to any external WSDL, you need to pass it as a complex data type. Simple data types will not be accepted as they dont follow the document literal type standard.